# I just want to connect react and socket io in a simple way, but the connection cannot be made

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

server/

version

"socket.io": "^4.0.0"

```
const express = require('express')
const socketio = require('socket.io')
const http = require('http')
const cors = require('cors')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
const app = express()
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = socketio(server)
app.use(cors())

io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('User has connected.')
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log("User has disconnected.")
    })
})

server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`))
```

client/

version socket io

"socket.io-client": "^4.0.0",

```
import './App.css';
import io from "socket.io-client"
import {useEffect,useState} from 'react'
let socket

function App() {

 
  useEffect(() => {

    socket = io("http://localhost:5000/")
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
     <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I tried every way but I couldn't get any results, I will be glad if you help.

Comment: You need to listen to the particular channel/message you suppose to correspond with i.e. `connection` in your case. 

e.g.

   socket.on('connection', (): void => {
      console.log('Progress Socket Connected.');
    });

Comment: Also, your backend/node implementation seems flawed, I am not sure about the current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Using import the documentation states that you should use  {}

Therefore:

```
// or with import syntax
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
```

https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-api/index.html

Comment: Although I did this, there was no connection anyway, when I print the socket value on the client side to the console, I get a json like this.

connected: false
disconnected: true

As far as I understand it should be connected true, but I wonder why?